# Visa-free visit and re-entry to the UK

Tags: visas, uk, visa-free-entry, new-zealand-citizens

I am an NZ passport holder travelling to the UK.

I understand that I can get 6 months visa free access there.

But, can I leave the country and return again within the six months?

I haven't been able to find any info about this on the UK immigration web page.

I intend to hire a car and visit Ireland via the Holyhead-Dublin ferry, and return to the UK in Scotland via the Belfast-Cairnryan ferry.

Comment: This is fine.  But note that you will be returning to the UK via the land border before you arrive in Belfast, which is in the UK.

Comment: It is fine to leave and reenter in any case, but you are also unlikely to see an immigration officer either in Dublin or when driving to Belfast. They likely won't know you left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During your six months, you may travel outside the UK (whether to Ireland, or France, Norway, Russia, whatever) and return to the UK with no problems whatsoever.

If you intend to do that over a longer period of time, such as 3 months in the UK, one month in France, 3 months in the UK, then they may have further questions for you.

As mentioned in the comments, if you only intend to go to Ireland by ferry then because that is within the [Common Travel Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Travel_Area), you may not see an immigration officer at all. If you do, then of course it's a good idea to have all your documentation in order as for any international border crossing.