# Re-entry to UK Resets Length of Stay Period?

Tags: uk, europe, long-stay-visas

Similar to the question here, [Visa-free visit and re-entry to the UK](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/98784/visa-free-visit-and-re-entry-to-the-uk), I have a similar but different question.

I am an SG passport holder, which allows me to be in the UK for 6 months.

Question 1:
If I leave UK and visit somewhere (i.e. France), does the 6 months reset when I return?

E.g. I leave UK on the 100th day. I travel to France for 7 days. When I return to UK, am I left with 80 days or it resets to 180 days?

Question 2: 
Schengen area has a limit of 90 days per 180 days. Is there something similar in UK?

Thanks!

Comment: My partner was questioned massively when we came back from a short trip from Amsterdam as they thought she was trying to reset her time(took her about 20 minutes of communication with the officer). She'd been in the UK for a couple of months before and was staying another couple of months so eventually the officer was satisfied she was only staying 4 months in total. She did receive another 6 months on her new stamp although she only used what she truthfully told the officer.

Comment: Thanks for this information! It is honestly more useful than my consulate. I was questioned for 10 minutes when I entered the country (March 2016, August 2017, January 2018) and they asked *super* personal questions. Thank you so much for replying!

Answer (score 5):

As I understand it, the UK has a rule that tourists may not "try to live in the UK" through successive visits, and that there is no *hard* formula. The border official would look at your case and decide if you are still a "visitor."

So if you feel you have to ask about "resets" there is a serious risk that a new entry will be refused.